# How can I configure Vi mode in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

I just learned about Vi mode in GHCi. I already added `editMode: Vi` to my ~/.haskeline file. There are two tasks that I wish to accomplish.

1. I would like to remap my escape key to `jj`.
2. I would like to configure GHCi to show me what mode I am in similar to how I can add `set show-mode-in-prompt on` to my `~/.inputrc` file for readline.

I have read through some of the [haskeline documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) but have not been able to find an answer.